# How to trigger javascript on node events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, express

I have a standard login page. When the database validates the credentials entered by the user I want to make changes to the page, example: create element saying "Login Successful", using a static javascript file. How do I communicate to a static javascript file that the login was successful thus triggering the changes? I'm using Parse right now for my database.

html:

```
<form class="form" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" name="username">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-custom" type="submit" id="loginSubmit" name="loginSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Node with Express and Parse:

```
login.post('/login', function (req, res) {

Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password, {
  success: function(user) {
    console.log("Login Successful!");
    res.redirect('/');
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    res.redirect('/login');
    console.log("Login Unsuccessful! " + error.message);
  }
});

});
```

Comment: You need something like Ajax for this, with the client explicitly asking the server the status after the button is pressed, and then generating a message on client-side.

Comment: Either you should use ajax for this or the html is to be rendered from server side, where the form will have an action attribute, which will land to a express router...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using jQuery's Ajax method.

```
$('#loginSubmit').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        //...
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log("fun time?");
                $('body').css("background-color", "yellow");
            }
        },
        complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
        }
    });
});
```